# Angular 6 rxjs observable not alert when next()

Tags: typescript, observable, angular6, rxjs6

I build a loading system for my game in typescript. I have some layer : Game > Scenes > Elements > Sprites > html image with load event. All waiting via observable.

First i have a sprite with multiple html image so i have a load function

```
  public load(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.loadingObs = new Observable((observer) => {
      const layerNames = Object.keys(this.conf.layers);
      let nLayer: number = 0;
      layerNames.forEach((k) => {
        this.loadImage(k).subscribe((loadResult) => {
          if (loadResult) {
            nLayer++;
          }

          if (nLayer === layerNames.length) {
            this.loaded = true;
            observer.next(true);
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      });
    });

    return this.loadingObs;
  }
```

And a method to retreive the observable

```
  public getLoadingObs(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loadingObs;
  }
```

The idea is : if a have N Element that want to load the same Sprite, i create an observable for my image load event, store the observable and give the observable for the next Element Wanting it. So when image loading is done, all Element receive the 'notification' via the observable subscribe. It work.

About Game > Scenes > Elements > Sprites, all is about the mechanic like

```
  public load(): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      let nRefs = 0;
      const spriteRefs = this.getSpritesRefs();

      // Load all needed sprites
      spriteRefs.forEach((ref) => {
        this.resources.loadSprite(ref).subscribe((loadFinished) => {
          if (loadFinished) {
            nRefs++;
          }

          if (nRefs === spriteRefs.length) {
            this.afterLoadInit();

            observer.next(true);
            observer.complete();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

My loadSprite service function get the new observable from sprite or retreive it like explain before. But i'm notified only when created and subscribed and never when retreive and subscribed. (It works just berfore)

So image loading is ok, some observable through all layer comunicate well, but not all. So if i wait 26 loading status, i receive 5 (5 real load), so why sudently observable not spread the next() function to all subscriber like before ?

I'm lost and i don't know tools or technics to debug observable more easily. I tried tap/do method without success. And console.log are mixed cause of async.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use eventEmitter instead of observable. More advised for broadcast problem.